# Let $A$ be a square complex matrix of size $n$ then $\langle Ax,x\rangle=0$ for $\forall x \in \Bbb C^n$ $\iff A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a Hermitian square complex matrix of size $n$ then $\langle Ax,x \rangle=0$,
>   $\forall x \in \Bbb C^n$ if and only if $A=0$

I want to know if the condition that $A$ is Hermitian is required for the statement to still hold, please?

Thank you

Comment: For prettier parentheses, use `\langle` and `\rangle` (producing $\langle Ax, x\rangle$) instead of `<` and `>` (producing $<Ax. x>$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the condition is required, as $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
shows.

For the matrix above, you can see that if $$z=\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\ z_2\end{bmatrix}$$

then $$\langle Az, z\rangle = \left\langle \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}z_1\\ z_2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}z_1\\ z_2\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle = \left\langle\begin{bmatrix}z_2\\ -z_1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}z_1\\ z_2\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle = z_2z_1 - z_1z_2 = 0$$

Comment: but A in this counter-example is not a complex matrix it's a real matrix

Comment: @Sweetstack Of course it is a complex matrix. $1$ is a complex number, isn't it? Or are you saying that $1\neq \mathbb C$?

Comment: @Sweetstack Why do you think $A$ is hermitian?

Comment: oh alright I am sorry your counter-example neglects the statement if A isn't hermition thanks sir

Comment: @Sweetstack I don't understand that sentence. But you're welcome :)

Comment: I mean that yeah the counter-example works I wasn't thinking straight with my other comments earlier

Comment: @Sweetstack Oh, OK. Happy to help!

Comment: Do we know that weaker condition would not suffice?